# What is the difference between "don't care" and "don't mind"?

Tags: meaning, differences

From an [English Help Online blog post](http://englishhelponline.me/2011/06/06/the-difference-between-words-dont-mind-and-dont-care/):

> “don’t mind” sounds very polite and gentle. It’s like the person is
>   saying “It’s ok with me.”; however, “don’t care” sounds stronger and
>   it’s like the person is saying, “It doesn’t matter to me”.`

I'm curious: is it really just a matter of stronger emphasis, or is there more to it?

Comment: All answers helped me to understand it better, but I find the distinguishing between `acceptance` and `indifference` by _Matthaeus_ the most helpful, therefore I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I have heard Englishmen say it, "I don't mind" was used only when the person using this expression wanted to express his moderate *acceptance* of the outcome of a situation.
"I don't care", however, can also be used to express *indifference* and to indicate that the outcome of a situation has no significance for you.

This may sometimes attribute a negative connotation to the message using this expression, whereas—as far as I know—"I don't mind" does not bear a negative connotation.
So "I don't mind" is replaceable by "I don't care", but not always the other way round.

> Child: "Mum, can I go out and play potentially dangerous ball games like football or soccer with my friends?"
>
> Mother: "**I don't mind**—the risk is worth the healthy consequences of sport, therefore I take notice and don't object"

OR

> Mother: "**I don't care**—do what you will, your activities do not concern me, I lack authority to form an opinion or I refuse to do so."

Answer (score 14):

There is a different meaning for *don't mind*, something like *don't object*.

But in the use you are talking about, the difference is as you've described. I think of it in terms of what's implied:

> I don't mind

means something like "thank you for asking, as I might have had a preference, but actually I don't care to express one. "

> I don't care

can mean something like "I haven't a preference, and there was no reason why you should think I might have."

Answer (score 5):

*Mind `X`* means to object to `X`.
*Care about `X`* means to have some interest in and feelings about `X`.

In the negative, then,

- *I **don't** mind `X`* = 'I have no objections to `X`'
- *I **don't** care about `X`* = 'I have no interest in or feelings about `X`'

Both can function as assent to a request for permission

- *I'm considering turning on the air conditioning.

  What do you think?*
- *I don't mind* ~ *I don't care* = 'Sure, go ahead'

Though, of course, they display different emotional attitudes.

Such negative statements seem extremely common in languages of the world for reassurance.
This is similar to the common English expressions
 *No problem(s), No trouble(s), No worries, Don't (you) worry ((your pretty little head) about it)*,
and the common Spanish expressions
 *De nada, No hay problema, No te preocupes (sobre eso)*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

While in some contexts it may be no more than a matter of emphasis, there is a substantive difference between the two:

"I don't care" conveys total dismissal of the subject to which it is applied, while "I don't mind" suggests that although it registers, it will not cause distress or disturbance.

edit: Rereading the original post, it seems the quote which prompted the question makes the same point. My contribution is therefore limited to pointing out that it actually is a substantive difference.

Comment: As an aside, your sentiments would apply when "I don't care" is a standalone thought (as opposed to being used in expressions like "I don't care for cake," which means something different, and doesn't imply any dismissal).

Comment: I believe "I don't care for" is a special case, and in any event would not be in a grouping with "I don't mind." Also, "I don't care" is always in response to something (explicitly or implicitly) and in that context conveys dismissal.

Comment: Yes, it is a special case, which is why I introduced my comment as an aside. :^)